# When I call the startActivity(i) the error is shown (see below) my code is Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewRecipe.class);

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.bullet.recipesearch, PID: 15986
>                                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.bullet.recipesearch/com.example.bullet.recipesearch.MainRecipe$NewRecipe}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
>                                                                                        at com.example.bullet.recipesearch.MainRecipe.fetchingfromlist(MainRecipe.java:182)
>                                                                                        at com.example.bullet.recipesearch.MainRecipe.access$000(MainRecipe.java:57)
>                                                                                        at com.example.bullet.recipesearch.MainRecipe$NewRecipe$1.onResponse(MainRecipe.java:117)
>                                                                                        at com.example.bullet.recipesearch.MainRecipe$NewRecipe$1.onResponse(MainRecipe.java:88)
>                                                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>                                                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>                                                                                        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Error says AcivityNotFound. I would start there. Since you didn't post any code, there's not much more that can be done to help you.

Comment: Please check whether activity is declared in manifest file or not ?

Comment: Your relevant code should go in the body of your post...not the title. And also please use code brackets to format code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Every activity has to be declared in Android Manifest file. Whenever you make an Activity go register it in the Manifest first. The error will go!
Here is a simple example of declaring the activity called `MainActivity`in Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Your can replace the `.` with your full package name like:

```
    <activity android:name="your_package_name.MainActivity"/>
```

The error above is because your activity is not registered.